# Delete a record from a table without affecting the associated tables

Tags: sql

I want to delete a record from a table (Material) in the database, and that record is an item from a table (InvoiceLine).
The tables are:

- Material - Contains MaterialID (FK), Name, and Note.
- InvoiceLine - Contains InvoiceLineID (FK), MaterialID, Quantity, and InvoiceID.

Example:

- Material table:

| MaterialID | Name | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mat1 |  |
| 2 | Mat2 |  |
| 3 | Mat3 |  |

- InvoiceLine Table By Select statement with Inner join on Material table:

| InvoiceID | MaterialName | Quantity | Price | Total | InvoiceID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mat1 | 50 | 100 | 5,000 | 1 |
| 2 | Mat2 | 100 | 150 | 15,000 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | **20,000** |  |

I want to keep the Select statement as they are without removing or changing any record from it so that the invoice amount is not affected.

Comment: Your wishes look incompatible. You want to delete something that you've forbidden to delete when created the FK. Provide DDL and sample data to clarify the case.

Comment: I think it is hard from database side but you can apply soft delete(By adding new field  in the Material table for IsDeleted).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It sounds like you want a soft delete, though.

Answer (score 1):

Normally deleting child table records can affect parent tables and cause database integrity violations but MySQL provides you with the ability to control what action will be taken when the referenced value in the parent table is updated or deleted, using the ON UPDATE and ON DELETE clauses. The supported actions that can be taken when deleting or updating the parent table’s values include:

**NO ACTION:** When the ON UPDATE or ON DELETE clauses are set to NO ACTION, the performed update or delete operation in the parent table will fail with an error.

**CASCADE:** Setting the ON UPDATE or ON DELETE clauses to CASCADE, the same action performed on the referenced values of the parent table will be reflected to the related values in the child table. For example, if the referenced value is deleted in the parent table, all related rows in the child table are also deleted.

**SET DEFAULT:** Using the SET DEFAULT option of the ON UPDATE and ON DELETE clauses specifies that, if the referenced values in the parent table are updated or deleted, the related values in the child table with FOREIGN KEY columns will be set to its default value.

In your case, **NO ACTION** would be helpful maybe...

```
ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }
```

NO ACTION means that nothing will happen when you delete from your Invoice items to the Amount.

(Sorry for the long text, hope this was helpful (: )